# How to get more information on failed FS pushes

Tags: foursquare

For a foursquare app it says at on the developer page:

15 failed pushes today

Is there a way to get additional information on those pushes, other then the fact the failed? Even a list of dates/times would be helpful, the entire failed push data would be ideal. I've been scouring the documentation but so far have had no luck.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get more information than that from Foursquare. Try checking your server's logs to see what may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Hall says in his comment, there's no way to get more information from foursquare other than the most recent error. You're best bet is to inspect your server logs for more information as to why the call failed.

Comment: Just realized I can see the last error, mine is: "Misc error occurred sending push out: class java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException" ... what in the world does that even mean :(